# RxJS5 WebSocketSubject - how to filter and complete messages?

Tags: websocket, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm looking for some guidance on the correct way to setup a WebSocket connection with RxJS 5. I am connecting to a WebSocket that uses JSON-RPC 2.0. I want to be able to execute a function which sends a request to the WS and returns an Observable of the associated response from the server.

I set up my initial WebSocketSubject like so:

`const ws = Rx.Observable.webSocket("<URL>")`

From this observable, I have been able to send requests using `ws.next(myRequest)`, and I have been able to see responses coming back through the ws` observable.

I have struggled with creating functions that will filter the ws responses to the correct response and then complete. These seem to complete the source subject, stopping all future ws requests.

My intended output is something like:

```
function makeRequest(msg) {
    // 1. send the message
    // 2. return an Observable of the response from the message, and complete
}
```

I tried the following:

```
function makeRequest(msg) {
    const id = msg.id;
    ws.next(msg);
    return ws
        .filter(f => f.id === id)
        .take(1);
}
```

When I do that however, only the first request will work. Subsequent requests won't work, I believe because I am completing with `take(1)`?

Any thoughts on the appropriate architecture for this type of situation?

Comment: the take operator indeed completes a sequence. Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: So each request that gets made will only have 1 matching response. Rather than keep checking all requests for an id that never comes again, I want to stop checking for this specific id once it comes back. I thought take() would close this sequence, but not the source observable with the websocket traffic. 

Does that make sense? Any ideas on the right way to structure this scenario?

Comment: To make sure I understand makeRequest is sending the request to the server? Meaning is it actually invokeServerRequest?

Comment: Can you provide and example of the code that uses makeRequest?

Comment: Ok @Meir here is what I am after... https://gist.github.com/skokenes/b30402b7c19c1dce595165a0e316feea

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be either a bug or a deliberate design decision to close the `WebSocket` on unsubscribe if there are no further subscribers. If you are interested here is the relevant [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L211-L217).

Essentially you need to guarantee that there is always a subscriber otherwise the `WebSocket` will be closed down.  You can do this in two ways.

Route A is the more semantic way, essentially you create a published version of the `Observable` part of the `Subject` which you have more fine grained control over.

```
const ws = Rx.Observable.webSocket("<URL>");
const ws$ = ws.publish();

//When ready to start receiving messages
const totem = ws$.connect();

function makeRequest(msg) {
    const { id } = msg;
    ws.next(msg);
    return ws$.first(f => f.id === id)
}

//When finished
totem.unsubscribe();
```

Route B is to create a token subscription that simply holds the socket, but depending on the actual life cycle of your application you would do well to attach to some sort of closing event just to make sure it always gets closed down. i.e.

```
const ws = Rx.Observable.webSocket("<URL>");

const totem = ws.subscribe();

//Later when closing:
totem.unsubscribe();
```

As you can see both approaches are fairly similar, since they both create a subscription. B's primary disadvantage is that you create an empty subscription which will get pumped all the events only to throw them away. They only advantage of B is that you can refer to the `Subject` for emission and subscription using the same variable whereas A you must be careful that you are using `ws$` for subscription.

If you were really so inclined you could refine Route A using the `Subject` creation function:

```
const safeWS = Rx.Subject.create(ws, ws$);
```

The above would allow you to use the same variable, but you would still be responsible for shutting down `ws$` and transitively, the `WebSocket`, when you are done with it.